# How to solve for a variable inside a summatory?

Tags: summation, systems-of-equations

I have a business where we buy cashier checks. The amount paid for a check is calculated as follows:
$$T = m -\frac{m*t*d_{i}}{30} - m*c,$$

where $T$ is the total paid, $m$ is the amount of the check, $t$ is the monthly interest rate, $d$ are the days remaining to the check date, and $c$ is a fixed cost.

Sometimes a person can bring multiple checks:
$$T = \sum_{i=1}^n \left( m_{i} - \frac{m_{i}*t*d_{i}}{30} - m_{i}*c \right).$$

Let's say the result in a case like this is not a rounded number, for example $\$1020$, and I want to charge the customer only $\$1000$.

How can I know the new $t$ given an arbitrary $T$ in the previous formula so I can know what was the interest rate applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean, something like this?
\begin{align}
T &= \sum_{i=1}^n \left( m_{i} - \frac{m_i t d_i}{30} -m_i c\right) \\
  &= \sum_{i=1}^n m_i(1-c) -\frac{t}{30} \sum_{i=1}^n m_i d_i \\ \\
\implies t &= 30 \cdot \dfrac{\displaystyle -T +\sum_{i=1}^n m_i(1-c)}{\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n m_k d_k} \\
\end{align}

But it may be easier to just write down the values ot $t$ in a list.

Comment: What do you mean with writing the values of _t_ in a list? _t_ is something I try to figure out every time

Comment: I realized _d_ should be d_{i}

Comment: Oh, I though $t$ would be given at least once. I changed the formula to accomodate the d_{i}.